# Property of the conjugate operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

First, this is my definition of conjugate operator:

> If $X,Y$ are normed spaces, and $T:X\to Y$ is a linear and continuous (bounded) operator between $X$ and $Y$ ($T\in L(X,Y)$), we define the conjugate operator of $T$ to be the applications $T^{\star}:Y^{\star}\to X^{\star}$, defined as follows:
> \begin{equation*}
> T^{\star}(g)=(g\circ T)\in X^{\star}, \forall g\in Y^{\star}
> \end{equation*}

I am proving some basic properties of this operator, and I am stuck in one of them...
First, some more definitions...

> If $A\subseteq X$, $A^{\perp}=\{f\in X^{\star}: f(x)=0, \forall x\in A\}$
>
> If $G\subseteq X^{\star}$, ${}^{\perp}G=\{x\in X: f(x)=0, \forall f\in G\}$

I have to prove that:
\begin{equation*}
{}^{\perp}R(T^{\star})=N(T)
\end{equation*}
where $R(T^{\star})=T^{\star}(Y^{\star})$ and $N(T)=T^{-1}(\{0\})$ (image and kernel, respectively).

My attempt has started proving that ${}^{\perp}R(T^{\star})\supseteq N(T)$: for this one, take $x\in N(T)$ and $g\in R(T^{\star})$ and let's prove that $g(x)=0$ (and then, $x\in {}^{\perp}R(T^{\star}))$. But this is direct, as there exists $f\in X^{\star}$ such that $T^{\star}(f)=g$, so
$$
g(x)=(T^{\star}(f))(x)=(f\circ T)(x)=f(T(x))=f(0)=0
$$
My problems comes when proving that ${}^{\perp}R(T^{\star})\subseteq N(T)$. What I have to see is that, if I take $x\in {}^{\perp}R(T^{\star})$, $Tx=0$. I know that, if $x\in {}^{\perp}R(T^{\star})$, $\forall g\in R(T^{\star})$, $g(x)=0$. But, I don't know how to conclude... Any guidance? Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $g \in Y^{*}$ we have $g(Tx)=T^{*}(g(x))=(T^{*}g) (x)=0$ since $T^{*} g \in R(T^{*})$. This implies that $Tx=0$ (by a standard application of Hahn-Banach Theorem).

Comment: Thanks for answering @geetha290krm ! I suppose that the application of the H-B Theorem is the one that says that: for all $y\in Y\setminus\{0\}$, there exists a $g\in Y^{\star}$ such that $||g||=1$ and $g(y)=||y||\neq 0$. So if $Tx\neq 0$, there would be an $g\in Y^{\star}$ such that $g(Tx)\neq 0$, and that is a contradiction with your answer... so $Tx=0$. Just writing it to check my understanding level of the situation... thanks again for the answer!

Comment: @rubikman23 That argument is perfect.